# fork/exec ./debug: operation not permitted

Tags: go, docker, delve

My goal is to be able to remote debug from [Atom.io](https://atom.io). into a docker container running go in [dlv debugger](https://github.com/derekparker/delve). This is the first problem:

Update:1. I am running Docker container on a mac, but that should not influence the code signing thing as I am running in a container, right?

Update:2. Codesignig the host, did not help.

```
Error:

1. root@...:/go/src/app# go get github.com/derekparker/delve/cmd/dlv

2. root@...:/go/src/app# dlv debug hello.go

could not launch process: fork/exec ./debug: operation not permitted
```

Then tried to

```
1. root@...:/go/src/app# sudo

2. bash: sudo: command not found
```

Comment: what container are you running?

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/_/golang/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to work if you start the container with `--privileged`. I've tried to figure out if there is a more fine-grained capability but failed.

Also I just found https://github.com/steeve/homebrew-delve which should make things easier on OSX.

Answer (score 5):

According [Delve Issue #515](https://github.com/derekparker/delve/issues/515)

> Docker has security settings preventing ptrace(2) operations by
>   default with in the container. Pass --security-opt seccomp:unconfined
>   to docker run when starting.

*confirmation of this in official docker bug tracker https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/21051

Answer (score 3):

Docker has security settings preventing ptrace(2)

See how i fixed it.

if using a docker-compose file to run the container then append `seccomp:unconfined` in the services section like below

```
api: 
  security_opt:
    - seccomp:unconfined
```

if using docker run ...passing `seccomp:unconfined` works as well

Answer (score 0):

Run Docker container as a command:

```
docker run -itd -p 2028:22 -p 2345:2345 --dns=10.236.8.8 --privileged=true --name=golang  centos7-golang  /usr/bin/supervisord
```

it works for me~